Adding a delay on consumption of messages with Spring JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer without using Delivery Delay
I have an implementation of DefaultMessageListenerContainer which will listen in on an IBM MQ Queue and something else publishes on this queue so whenever a message arrives, the listener consumes the message and certain steps on an overridden onMessage() method are performed.
Each time a message has arrived on this queue, i want it to be queued there until a set time has elapsed and only then want the steps of my overridden onMessage() method to get executed
Deliverydelay is not supported for me so that is not an option.
Adding a delay while publishing to the queue is also not an option.
The delay has to be during consumption, and even if there are 10 messages on the queue, each message will only be consumed after a set delay.

Add the delay in your onMessage() method?

Do you want the delay BEFORE the message is removed from the queue or AFTER it is removed from the queue and before it is processed.

@MoragHughson BEFORE the message is even removed from the queue

You'll have to code that in your application before you drive message retrieval. You haven't showed us your code, so not sure what to advise.
